# Zend_Service_Yahoo showing sending request error. Status code: 404

Tags: zend-framework

I need your help.
I am facing a problem using Zend_Service_Yahoo.
I am trying to use Zend_Service_Yahoo. But it shows

"**An error occurred sending request. Status code: 404**"

```
$yahoo = new Zend_Service_Yahoo("YAHOO_APPLICATION_ID");

     try{

            $results = $yahoo->imageSearch('PHP');

            foreach ($results as $result) {
                echo $result->Title . '<br />';
            }

        }catch(Exception $e){

           echo $e->getMessage();

        }
```

Reference : http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.0/en/zend.service.yahoo.html

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

That's because imagesearch [has been deprecated](http://developer.yahoo.com/search/image/V1/imageSearch.html).

> We’re shutting down this service in April 2011. For further details, please see the Deprecated Services blog post.